# PowerApps Studio- Permissions - Premium Plan

Tags: permissions, access, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have a co-worker who built an app in PowerApps, but utilized a lot of features in his PowerApps Premium plan.  He made me a co-owner of the app, but I don't have a Premium account.  In the app I see a lot of sections/fields that are blank with an error message "you don't have permission to view this data".  He made me a co-owner, so I thought I should be able to see these fields.  But I also don't have that Premium subscription.  Would my lack of the Premium Plan be the cause of these errors?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like it is genuinely a permissions issue, not a licensing issue. Having co-owner access to the app does not automatically grant you permissions to the underlying data sources.

If I try to access a premium app with a non-premium license, I get this error:

> You do not have a valid Power Apps plan. To access Power Apps you must
> have a Power Apps plan assigned to you by your organization or the
> organization in which you’re a guest.

Comment: Thanks!  This is also what I've found.  Looks like I need a System Administrator security role in Dynamics 365.